# how to Write a script to read the data from the `MongoDB` database and produce a `JSON` file as the given format

Tags: mongodb

I have four collections.

CollegeLocation -- Json format

```json
{
    "MDTC": {
        "collegeName": "College of Medicine - Tucson",
        "1002": 10,
        "1001": 234
    },
    "SCNC": {
        "collegeName": "College of Science",
        "1002": 24,
        "1003": 21,
        "1001": 16
    },
    "LAWC": {
        "collegeName": "James E Rogers College of Law",
        "1002": 234,
        "1003": 213
    }
}
```

LocationEmployeeDetails -- Json format

```json
{
        "1002": {
            "loc_id": "1002",
            "kmapids": [
                "palmerjo",
                "cwesterl",
                "lumbee"
            ]
        },
        "1001": {
            "loc_id": "1001",
            "kmapids": [
                "skaib",
                "dcorso",
                "ghuck",
                "macmccallum"
            ]
        },
        "1003": {
            "loc_id": "1003",
            "kmapids": [
                "ghuck",
                "cwesterl",
                "dcorso",
                "witte",
                "lumbee"
            ]
        }
    
}
```

LocationDetails - json

```json
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    32.0,
                    49.0
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "country": "Ukraine",
                "city": "",
                "name": "Ukraine",
                "state": "",
                "loc_id": "1001"
      
                 
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -4.0,
                    40.0
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "country": "Spain",
                "city": "",
                "name": "Spain",
                "state": "",
                "loc_id": "1002"
            }
        },

        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.087749,
                    41.6032207
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "country": "United States",
                "city": "",
                "name": "Connecticut",
                "state": "Connecticut",
                "loc_id": "1003"
            }
        }
 
    ]
}
```

EmployeeDetails - csv

```
name    kmapId  college fullname    collegeid
J Palmer    palmerjo    College of Medicine - Tucson    John Palmer MDTC
C Westerland    cwesterl    College of Social  and  Behav Sci   Chad Westerland SBSC
R Williams  lumbee  James E Rogers College of Law   Robert Williams LAWC
S Kaib  skaib   College of Medicine - Phoenix   Susan Kaib  MDPX
M Witte witte   College of Medicine - Tucson    Marlys Witte    MDTC
S Dougherty shonad  College of Medicine - Tucson    Shona Dougherty MDTC
D Corso dcorso  College of Fine Arts    Dawn Corso  FNRT
G Huckleberry   ghuck   College of Science  Gary Huckleberry    SCNC
D Mccallum  macmccallum James E Rogers College of Law   David Mccallum  LAWC
```

- `location_details.json`: contains locations details with location id `loc_id`
- `location_employee_details.json`: contains a list of the employees (`kmapids`) associated with each location.
- `employee_details.csv`: contains employees `kmapid`, `name`, and `college`
- `colleges_location_values.json`: contains college values for each location.
- `sample_output.json`: example of output format

Question 1 - How to Write a script to import `location_details.json`, `location_employee_details.json`, `employee_details.csv`, and `colleges_location_values.json` to a `MongoDB` database.

Question 2 - How to Write a script to read the data from the `MongoDB` database and produce a `JSON` file as the given format `sample_output.json`. The code should work for the variable length of data.

Not sure how to

- Write a script to import `location_details.json`, `location_employee_details.json`, `employee_details.csv`, and `colleges_location_values.json` to a `MongoDB` database.
- Write a script to read the data from the `MongoDB` database and produce a `JSON` file as the given format `sample_output.json`. The code should work for the variable length of data.

Comment: It's not clear what, exactly, you're asking for.  For example, what scripts are you trying to write? MongoDB has import and export tools, and they are well-documented - have you tried using those? If so: what specific issue(s) did you run into when using them? It's important to include these specifics. Also note that, as written, this really isn't a programming question; it's more of a database-administration question (maybe try on dba.stackexchange.com?). Just note that, even on the dba stack exchange, this would likely be off-topic, as you haven't shown any work.

Comment: Also: your data, marked as csv? That's not csv, and cannot be imported as such. For csv, you would need some consistent delimiter like a comma. And even a space isn't a valid delimiter in your case, as you have spaces in your data.

Comment: Final note: your very last bullet, about creating variable-length data, doesn't really make sense without more specifics. When you edit (or repost elsewhere), you should be very specific about what that means, what your intended output looks like, what you tried, what it *actually* looks like, errors, etc.